# What is the code for the Halmos tombstone?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I have a quote where Halmos writes "The symbol▐ is used throughout ...". What is the tex-code for the Halmos tombstone, and what package is needed for it?

Comment: You mean [this](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=end+of+proof)?

Comment: So this is not the 'black Halmos tombstone' mentioned in your other question? Who's Halmos and how many tombs does he/she or it have?

Comment: Yeah, really: maybe we can have just one question about this given that it is not really a mysterious problem. I'm sure Gonzalo Medina could consolidate his answers pretty easily....

Comment: Paul Halmos is a renowned set theorist, and he introduced the tombstone in his important book Measure theory in 1950.

Comment: @cfr The problem is that there's not a unique form for the tombstone or end-mark: it can be a filled or empty rectangle or square, but it's also common to see a square with a checkmark inside...

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Oh, right. Halmos & set theory.  Thanks. OK. Now I have a sense of who he is. Just I didn't remember seeing the name out of context. (I didn't know anything about his many tombstones.)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina One may read some about the tombstone and other symbols here: http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html

Thanks for the \rule[-2pt]{4pt}{8pt} which I settled for.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I didn't know it and it has useful information (some of which I already knew, but some is new).

Comment: Me, I prefer to use Paulo's duck: http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5493

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps `\RectangleBold` or `\Rectangle` from the [`bbding`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbding) package? Or make your own symbol using a `\rule` (no packages required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbding}

\newcommand\MyRectangle{\rule{.36em}{2ex}}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleBold}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A test text.
\end{proof}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\Rectangle}

\begin{proof}
A test text.
\end{proof}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\MyRectangle}

\begin{proof}
A test text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In TeX Live, this will not be scalable because only metafont source is available. (Don't know that this matters but it might be a consideration.)

Comment: Who's Halmos..?

Comment: I actually tried this out on account of the advice giving in the linked document, but in my document it only produces a v:

http://tex.findincity.net/view/635399273629833626106368/tombstone-symbol-in-latex

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal notice that theres no `$...$` around the symbol.

Comment: Thanks! This is useeful for me in some documents I write as I there use a black square with a different technical meaning,

Answer (score 7):

There are also blocks of different thicknesses in the Zapf Dingbats supported by `pifont`. Unlike `bbding`, these will be scalable even with a default TeX Live installation (which does not include the type1 versions of `bbding` for licensing reasons).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,pifont}

\begin{document}

  \ding{120} \ding{121} \ding{122} \ding{110}

\begin{proof}
  A proof. For control purposes.
\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{120}}
\begin{proof}
  A proof. Thinner.
\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{121}}
\begin{proof}
  A proof. Thin.
\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{122}}
\begin{proof}
  A proof. Normal.
\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{110}}
\begin{proof}
  A proof. Square.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: pifont options]